# How do you add Fedex SmartPost as a shipping option?

Tags: drupal-6, ubercart, fedex

I am looking to add FedEx SmartPost as a shipping option. Any idea what I need to do to accomplish this? The only information I have found on it is here https://drupal.org/node/793124, but it seems no one has solved this issue. I am willing to modify the ubercart fedex module if needed.

So far what I have done:

- Changed `RateService_v10.wsdl` to `RateService_v14.wsdl`
- Added code to the `uc_fedex_rate_request` function:

  ```
  $request['RequestedShipment']['SmartPostDetail'] = addSmartPostDetail();
  function addSmartPostDetail(){
    $smartPostDetail = array( 
       'Indicia' => 'PARCEL_SELECT',
       'AncillaryEndorsement' => 'CARRIER_LEAVE_IF_NO_RESPONSE',
       'SpecialServices' => 'USPS_DELIVERY_CONFIRMATION',
       'HubId' => 5087,
       'CustomerManifestID' => myid, 
     );
    return $smartPostDetail;
  }
  ```

In the `uc_fedex_quote` function, I have added a debug statement right after:

```
  $response = uc_fedex_rate_request($packages, $origin, $destination);
  drupal_set_message('<pre>'. print_r($response, TRUE) .'</pre>');
```

In the response I do not get SmartPost returned as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I had to do (note: I edited the uc_fedex.module directly):

- You must get SmartPost approved for your account first
- Get the updated wsdl file from https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/process.html?tab=tab1 and upload them to your server
- Get a HubId from customer support (mine was 5185)
- Get a CustomerManifestID from customer support
- Change to RateService_v14.wsdl in the code (near $client = new SoapClient...)
- Change the version to 14

  $request['Version'] = array(
      'ServiceId'    => 'crs',
      'Major'        => '14',
      'Intermediate' => '0',
      'Minor'        => '0',
  );
- Add the following code:

  $request['RequestedShipment']['SmartPostDetail'] = addSmartPostDetail();
  function addSmartPostDetail(){
    $smartPostDetail = array( 
      'Indicia' => 'PARCEL_SELECT',
      'AncillaryEndorsement' => 'CARRIER_LEAVE_IF_NO_RESPONSE',
      'SpecialServices' => 'USPS_DELIVERY_CONFIRMATION',
      'HubId' => yourhubid,
      'CustomerManifestID' => yourmanifestid, 
    );
    return $smartPostDetail;
  }
- Add the following to _uc_fedex_ground_services(): 'SMART_POST' => t('FedEx Smart Post'),
- Go to admin/store/settings/quotes/methods/fedex and check 'FedEx Smart Post'

Answer (score 0):

AllisonC's answer was very helpful. For anyone setting up SmartPost API calls with Drupal + Ubercart, here's how I built on her solution using FedEx Shipping 7.x-2.0+23-dev.

- Download an updated RateService_vXX.wsdl file from http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/process.html?tab=tab1 (current version is v18). Open the wsdl file in a text editor and make sure it is connecting to the FedEx production server (currently ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/). Upload this file to /uc_fedex/wsdl-production/.
- Edit the uc_fedex.module as follows (line numbers may vary, depending on how you edit the file):

  1. Consider disable caching of SOAP WSDL while testing (line 19).
  2. Define the addSmartPostDetail function as follows, outside the uc_fedex_quote function (I used line 248):

     function addSmartPostDetail(){
       $smartPostDetail = array( 
         'Indicia' => 'PARCEL_SELECT',
         'HubId' => '5185', // use 5531 for testing only
       );
      return $smartPostDetail;
     }
  3. Inside the uc_fedex_quote function (line 271), call the addSmartPostDetail function.

     $request['RequestedShipment']['SmartPostDetail'] = addSmartPostDetail();
  4. Add the following to the _uc_fedex_ground_services() array (line 857):

     'SMART_POST' => t('FedEx Smart Post'),
  5. Define package dimensions (line 544). SmartPost has minimum container sizes of 6" L, 4" W, 1" H, and the module's hardwired settings are not adequate.

     'Dimensions' => array(
     'Length' => 6,
     'Width'  => 4,
     'Height' => 1,
     'Units'  => 'IN',
     ),
  6. I also manually patched the .module file using the patch at https://www.drupal.org/node/1782298 to avoid an unhelpful "Recoverable fatal error" notice if the request didn't work correctly.
- Go to admin/store/settings/quotes/methods/fedex and check "FedEx Smart Post'.

My client needed to set conditions separately for Home Delivery and Smart Post, and didn't use any Express services, so I moved the 'SMART_POST' => t('FedEx Smart Post'), snippet to the _uc_fedex_express_services() array, enabled the FedEx Express method, and then set conditions accordingly.